# How do I change the backup retention period in Autonomous Database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

Is there anyway to change the backup retention? I have not found any way to change that and we want to confirm if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

ADB stores backups (database and archivelogs) for 60 days as documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/backup-intro.html#GUID-3BF27FDE-F847-4A86-9C8B-4ED9B0C1D1B2). You can restore a database in-place, or you can create a new database from any point in time in the last 60 days.

Currently, there's no way to change the backup retention.

As an alternative, you can do [Data Pump exports](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/export-data-other-database-dp.html#GUID-AB5F3773-EAD3-4E49-963D-69E8ECFBF116) to the object store and keep the dump files based on your retention requirements.